# how do i sort a list using count of vowels tried this ..but isnt going right

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
def conut(words):
    vowels = "aeiou"
    s= 0
    for a in words[0:5]:
        for x in vowels[0:len(vowels)]:
            s = s + (a.count(x))
words= ["elephant","apple","kat"]
b = words.sort(key = conut(words))
```

Comment: You don't have a `return` statement in your function.

Comment: the problem is have a list of elements i need to sort according to the count of vowels ?how can i do it?

Comment: I can see what you're trying to do. You have to provide a function that returns the number of vowels. Your function doesn't return anything, that's the first thing you need to fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `str.count(sub[, start[, end]])`: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count

```
def vowelscount(word):
    return sum([word.count(x) for x in 'aeiou'])

test = ['aaa', 'aeiouoiea', 'aiuola']
sorted(test, key=vowelscount)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `sorted` with a custom comparison:

```
def num_vowels(word):
     count = 0
     for c in word:
         if c in "aeiou":
             count += 1
     return count

>>>> test = ["aeaeaeaeaeaeae","ace","aeiouios"]
>>>> sorted(test, key=num_vowels)
['ace', 'aeiouios', 'aeaeaeaeaeaeae']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter` to count the number of char in the strings. and then sum the ones that you're interested in, in this case vowels.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> def vowelcounts(word):
...     vowels = "aeiou"
...     return sum([j for i,j in Counter(word).items() if i in vowels])
... 
>>> test = ["aeaeaeaeaeaeae","ace","aeiouios"]
>>> sorted(test, key=vowelcounts)
['ace', 'aeiouios', 'aeaeaeaeaeaeae']
```